# Why is strings faster on a file than it is on stdin?

Tags: macos, command-line

I wouuld have assumed it would take similar time, maybe 30% difference at most, but it's wayy off.

Are there any reasons for this?

With Zsh:

[image: Demonstration]

And with different shells:

[image: Demo with Bash, Sh, and Fish]

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem of `strings`, it's a problem of pipes in OSX.

Whatever you do, sending data through a pipe is horribly slow, especially if the read and write sizes are not aligned. Try something along the lines of

```
cat somefile | cat | cat | cat | cat | cat | strings
```

to get an idea how much those pipes slow down processing.

Comment: Is this an OS X thing, or is it also present on linux?

Comment: This is an OSX implementation defect.

Comment: The examples given don't involve pipes, just plain input redirects.

Comment: Which of course are implemented as .... pipes!